# How to change horizontal axis from Category to Value with Line Chart type in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two number data columns.  When I plot them with *line graph type* and make the first column data as the x-axis (horizontal) data, Excel plots the horizontal data as Horizontal (Category) axis instead of Horizontal (Value) axis.  I want to manipulate the x-axis data and not having it labeled as text.  I need to make the Horizontal (Category) axis to become Horizontal (Value) axis.  To do this, I found that I need to change the **Graph Type** to **Scatter** graph type.

From my research, I am not sure if I got the answer.  The answers to the questions that I found don't seem to be direct.  What I found works for me temporarily, but is it the only way (or solution) to do it.

So, does anyone know how make the Horizontal (Category) axis to become Horizontal (Value) axis for **Line Graph**?  Or, is changing the Graph Type to Scatter the only way?

Comment: "want to manipulate the x-axis data and not having it labeled as text." how does the x axis data looks like?  ( In the scatter graph type there IS one that have line. Isn't that close enough.. )

Comment: Thanks @p._phidot_.  Using scatter graph type is close enough, but I am looking for a clear answer that it can't be done with the line graph type.  I assume it's not but have yet to find documentation that say so.